# How to select between the top 50 and 100 returned (queried) rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, range

Using MSSQL, how can I skip the first set of 50 records, return the next set of 50, and exclude any remaining records from a query. Essentially, something like what one would imagine the following code would do where identitynumber is the identity of the record.

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM dbo.users
WHERE users.name = 'John' AND IDENTITYNUMBER >=50 AND IDENTITYNUMBER <=100
```

Comment: `Offset fetch` - but you need an ordering criteria.

Comment: I'll add that in. I already order by users.name, but forget to include it here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess you need the OFFSET keyword.

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary 
FROM employees 
ORDER BY salary DESC 
OFFSET 5 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Or in your case:

```
select * from dbo.Users
where name = 'John'
order by users.name
offset 50 rows
fetch next 50 rows only;
```

Source: https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-fetch/

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I can pass server parameters into the statement as well, to change the range, which is precisely what I needed. I'm able to load, search, and scroll through records now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ROW_NUMBER()

```
CREATE TABLE #users ( id int, name varchar(100) )

INSERT INTO #users
VALUES (1,'John'),(2,'John'),(3,'John'),(4,'Not John'),(5,'John')

SELECT TOP(2) x.*
FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rowNumber
        FROM #users
        WHERE name = 'John'
     ) AS x
WHERE x.rowNumber > 2

DROP TABLE #users
```

[Check this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a04b3e/1)

Answer (score -1):

Give something like this a go

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.users
WHERE users.name = 'John'
ORDER BY users.name
OFFSET 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Multiple syntax errors. `;` in the middle of the query. `WHERE` must be before the `ORDER BY` which itself is missing and should be before the `OFFSET`...